# Angular uislider Disable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I am using Angular [UI Slider](https://github.com/prajwalkman/angular-slider). Slider is working as expected. But I dont know how to disable it. I tried ng-disabled and  few other things, it dint worked out.

Any idea on how I should disable this?

Comment: did you try ng-disabled?

Comment: Yes its not working!!!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to disable the slider statically. You have to edit the angular-slider.js, so that the first command of the function *onMove* (should start in line 259) states

```
if ('disabled' in attributes) {return}
```

Then your html should look like

```
<slider disabled floor=0 ceiling=100 step=1></slider>
```

Unfortunately you can't change the disabled status during runtime this way, like you could when using *ng-disabled="someCondition"*. One way to manage this around the corner, which I eventually did is something like:

```
<div ng-if="sliderHasToBeDisabled">
    <slider disabled ...>
</div>
<div ng-if="!sliderHasToBeDisabled">
    <slider ...>
</div>
```

If there is a more elegant and clean way, I'm still interested.

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

I just saw that you are not using the same Angular UI Slider app as me. Since your library is not longer maintained, I can recommend the   [jQuery UI Slider for AngularJS](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-slider). With that lib, you can do what I wrote originally:

---

With

```
<div ui-slider="sliderOptions" ng-model="value"></div>
```

you can set the `sliderOptions` with

```js
$scope.sliderOptions = {
    disabled: true
};
```

and also change `$scope.sliderOptions.disabled` while running the app.